# ruby delete_at tune up

Tags: ruby

I have working code but don't like it, its very unruby like to me. I have two different collections and am wanting to remove elements that have matching keys from one collection. I have "picked" which the user has picked from "choices". So I only want to display "choices" that are not already picked. Here is the code:

```
@picked.each do |p|
  i = 0
  @choices.each do |c|
    if p.choices_id == c.id 
      @choices.delete_at(i)
      break
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

end

I don't like the variable "i" in particular. Just thought that I'd see what others might do with this.

Comment: What is `choices_id`? `Object#id` is depreciated. You should use `Object#object_id` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@choices.reject! { |c| @picked.index { |p| p.choices_id == c.id } }
```

Comment: Wow! Really succinct! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/Enumerator/each_with_index) and [with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/Enumerator/with_index) for Ruby 1.9+

And improvement for your code

```
choices_ids = @picked.map(&:choices_id)
@choices.delete_if{ |c| choices_ids.include? c.id }
```

api: [delete_if](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)

**UPD**

Also you can always simply call this:

```
@choices - @picked.map(&:choices).flatten
```

or

```
@choices -= @picked.map(&:choices).flatten
```

Comment: Huh, have not seen that "&" used before or even know what it means, so have something new to learn, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby supports intersection and difference for sets:

```
picked  = %w[1 2 3]
choices = %w[1 2 3 4 5]

choices - picked # => ["4", "5"]
```

---

EDIT:

```
class Pick
  attr_reader :choices_id
  def initialize(id)
    @choices_id = id
  end
end

class Choice
  attr_reader :id
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end
end

# cobble up some collections of objects 
picked = %w[1 2 3].map{ |p| Pick.new(p) }
choices = %w[ 1 2 3 4 5].map{ |c| Choice.new(c) }

choices.map{ |c| c.id } - picked.map{ |p| p.choices_id } # => ["4", "5"]
```

Comment: I would have used this, but both were collections of objects that were different. Thanks. Can't wait until I actually can use something like this in production code, 'cause its what little of Ruby I know!

Comment: OK. I guess I'll have to explain it a bit more.